# Excel VBA Match function to take either String or Integer variables as Arg1

Tags: excel, vba, match, worksheet-function, variant

The following is part of a longer code. 
How can I declare Arg1 in `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` to be either an Integer or a String?

I have data (numbers) in column A and numbers with underscores in column B.

The user would enter either a number or a string in an inputbox and the match function will try to match the user input in column A but if it not matched, then it would try to match it in column B and return the match row.

However, the matching will only work either if I use `Dim userinput As Integer` and that would be able to match in column A only; or use `Dim userinput As String` and that would be able to match it in column B only. Declaring `Dim userinput As Variant` would work just similar to `Dim userinput As String`.

I could do some workaround but I would like to understand first why it is not able to match it in column A when declaring it as Variant?

Following is the data I have in columns A and B, respectively.

```
W   WB
25  25_0
25  25_1
25  25_2
25  25_2
25  25_3
25  25_3
25  25_3
26  26_0
26  26_0
26  26_0
26  26_1
26  26_1
```

Following is the code:

```
Sub Return_Row()
Dim userinput As Variant, search_rng As Range

userinput = InputBox("Enter your number")

Set search_rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")

On Error Resume Next
N = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(userinput, search_rng, 0)
On Error GoTo 0

If N = 0 Then
    Set search_rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B:B")
    N = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(userinput, search_rng, 0)
End If

MsgBox N
End Sub
```

Comment: You can always add `If IsNumeric(userinput) Then userinput = CDec(userinput)` after the inputbox line.

Comment: `Inputbox` will return a string even if the user enters a number: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/inputbox-function

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Scott Craner, it worked!. It is my first time to learn about the CDec function.

This way (using the Val function) is also working.

```
Sub Return_Row()
Dim search_rng As Range

userinput = InputBox("Enter your number")

On Error Resume Next
If IsNumeric(userinput) Then
    userinput = Val(userinput)
    Set search_rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
    N = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(userinput, search_rng, 0)
Else
    Set search_rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B:B")
    N = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(userinput, search_rng, 0)
End If

On Error GoTo 0


MsgBox N
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim userinput
    userinput = Application.InputBox("your value", Type:=3)

Select Case TypeName(userinput)
    Case "Double"
        'do the numeric match
    Case "String"
        'do the string match
    Case Boolean
        'Cancel button routine
End Select
End Sub
```

`Application.InputBox` unlike `InputBox` (which is really `VBA.InputBox`), allows you to specify the return types.

As @MathieuGuindon points out, there are some benefits to using `VarType` instead of `TypeName`.  Below is code using the latter:

```
Option Explicit
Sub foo()
    Dim userinput
    userinput = Application.InputBouserinput("your value", Type:=3)

Select Case VarType(userinput)
    Case vbDouble
        'do the numeric match
    Case vbString
        'do the string match
    Case vbBoolean
        'Cancel button was pressed
        Stop
End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I would advise using `Select Case VarType(userinput)` and thus switch over a built-in enum rather than using `TypeName` and dealing with hard-coded strings.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon In general, I would agree with you. I chose `TypeName` in this instance thinking it would provide some clarity to the OP, but clearly, using `vbDouble` and `vbString` would have been equally illuminating, and less prone to typos.

Comment: Thank you very much Ron! I started exploring the `Application.InputBox` method and it is very interesting. I wish I knew about this long time ago